# Databricks - export dataset to a raster file in DBFS using rioxarray

Tags: databricks, raster, azure-databricks, python-xarray

I am trying to follow [simple example in rioxarray documentation](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/convert_to_raster.html) to export a dataset to a raster file in DBFS.

Install the library:

```
%pip install rioxarray
```

Run example code from the docs (input dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/blob/master/test/test_data/input/PLANET_SCOPE_3D.nc)):

```
import rioxarray
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/PLANET_SCOPE_3D.nc", decode_times=False)
rds.isel(time=0).rio.to_raster("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/planet_scope.tif")
```

However, when I list the files in the directory (`dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/FileStore/tables")`) the file `planet_scope.tif` is not present.

How can I export dataset to raster file in DBFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is caused by the [limitations of the DBFS local file API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations), although the library doesn't throw the exception - just simply don't create a file.

The solution would be to output raster to the local disk, and copy file into the DBFS using `dbutils.fs.cp`:

```py
import rioxarray
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/PLANET_SCOPE_3D.nc", decode_times=False)
rds.isel(time=0).rio.to_raster("/tmp/planet_scope.tif")
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/planet_scope.tif", "/FileStore/tables/planet_scope.tif", True)
```

Comment: If you do not want to keep file on local disk you can also use dbutils.fs.mv rather than dbutils.fs.cp

Comment: local copy will disappear when you stop/restart the cluster